# 'before' or 'in front of'?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which sentence is the correct one?

1. He parked his BMW directly ***before*** the diner.

*or*

2. He parked his BMW directly ***in front of*** the diner.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that simple proofreading is off-topic here; why do you believe one or the other is incorrect, and what research have you already attempted? I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: Both are acceptable, though the use of *before* in the sense of "in front of," that is, with reference to place as opposed to time, is considered old fashioned now. This usage is found mostly in legal writing (presented before the judge/court) or such.

Comment: Old fashioned? 1. "*The man came before the king and begged his forgiveness.*" A sentence still frequently read to little children. 2. "*The house burned to the ground before my very eyes.*" *Before* is frequently used in preference to *in front of* when the entity being confronted is huge in size, stature or abstractness. "*The winner wept in joy before a roaring thunderous crowd*". You would say "I stood before the wall of silence." because the wall is so huge or so abstract that you could never be *in front of it*.

Comment: @BlessedGeek: good examples, but I would say that 1. is indeed old-fashioned, just as the language in much of our children's literature is. As for 2., I wonder if it's not about the size of the entity but the activity. While "in front of," is simply about location, "before" may be used to indicate  a sense of "witnessing." It would be odd to say "the house burned to the ground in front of my eyes," because it's not about location, per se, but about the witnessing. Same applies to "the winner wept in joy..." Using "in front of" there makes the location of the weeping almost seem incidental...

Comment: @Rusty Tuba I agree that there are old-fashioned &/or formal, and 'in the presence of [a person]' connotations for locative/directional 'before' that may be present singly or together. I think we also have to consider a connotation of awesomeness: he stood before the largest tree he had ever seen.

Comment: @edwin. That is true. Good example.

Comment: I cannot agree with the close votes. There's little for opinion here.

Comment: _Before_ is more used in time metaphors than to designate space. Of course, not everything has a front -- trees, lakes, fields, etc, [as Fillmore points out](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/2-Space.pdf), don't.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are correct, but the first is very formal. The use of ***before*** with the meaning of ***in front of*** is labelled as *formal* by dictionaries, some even say it is *[antiquated](https://www.google.com/search?q=before%20meaning&source=hp&ei=gU7jY-6QO9T9gAb3hYqIDw&iflsig=AK50M_UAAAAAY-NckvJZ0sCScgVYzAmjUxEm_wvDEL0Y&oq=before%20mea&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADINCAAQgAQQsQMQRhD5ATIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDoUCC4QgAQQsQMQgwEQxwEQ0QMQ1AI6CwgAEIAEELEDEIMBOg4ILhCABBCxAxDHARDRAzoICAAQgAQQsQM6EQguEIAEELEDEIMBEMcBENEDOggIABCxAxCDAToLCC4QgAQQsQMQgwE6CAguELEDEIMBOg4ILhCDARDUAhCxAxCABDoFCC4QgAQ6DgguEIAEELEDEIMBENQCOggILhCABBCxAzoICC4QsQMQgAQ6CAguEIAEENQCUABYmA1g9RhoAHAAeACAAUqIAecEkgECMTCYAQCgAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)*, though I would not go so far.

> If someone is ***before*** something, they are ***in front of*** it.
> [formal]
>
> - They drove through a tall iron gate and stopped ***before** a large white villa*. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/before))

It has remained as part of some idioms such as

> ***appear before*** 
> To participate in legal proceedings.
>
> - Every lawyer is nervous when they have to *appear **before** a judge* for the first time. ([FreeDictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/appear+before))

or

> ***before (one's) eyes***
> Right in front of one or while one is watching.
>
> - Someone smashed into my parked car right before my eyes. ([FreeDictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/before+(one%27s)+eyes))

Answer (score -1):

Your number two is the correct one. You'd use the preposition "in front of."

Comment: Pray, why should that be?

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence could mean *He parked his BMW immediately before the person who was eating parked their car.* The second sentence most likely means *He parked his BWM at the location directly at the front of the eatery*, which is no doubt what is intended.

*before* in this context is often understood to be time related while *in front of* is understood to be spatially related.

**EDIT**

Changed "means" to "could mean".

Comment: -1 Please see a good dictionary.

Comment: Also for the meaning of *diner.*

Comment: @Kris _Diner_ can be the agent noun: _diner n.
1. One that dines: midnight diners enjoying the meal after the theater.
2. See dining car.
3. A small, usually inexpensive restaurant with a long counter and booths and housed in a building designed to resemble a dining car.
The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language //
diner n
1. (Commerce) a person eating a meal, esp in a restaurant

Collins English Dictionary_ // Though the answerer's explanation is rather contrived (needs a lot of contextualising), it's probably as valid as one requiring a now rare usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's obvious from the context that the "diner"' is a place, not a person.

Comment: @Kris So how does that make this answer deserve a downvote? Answerer is commenting validly on the [possible] meaning/s associated with OP's examples. 'Before' is usually reserved for temporal usage nowadays.

Answer (score -1):

You use "in front of" when you have a local relationship in mind. Typical example: in front of the house, behind the house.

You use "before" when you have a temporal relationship in mind as in: before the war, after the war.

And you can use "before" when talking of order or things as in: The letter A stands before B.